# Bash script for creating symbolic links

Tags: finder, bash, symlink

I am relatively new to bash and am having some trouble with a script I am trying to write. After spending the last hour or so researching and trying new techniques, I am still unable to do what I would like.

My goal is this: I have a folder `/Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos` where I keep all of my pictures. Each folder is titled `YYYY-MM FolderName` where there are sometimes spaces in `FolderName`. Within these folders are three folders: `Raw`, `Edited`, and `Final`. My goal is to, with a single bash script, create symbolic links on my Desktop for each `Final` folder AND rename it to its parent folder. Example: I would like `/Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos/2016-10\ Fleet\ Week/Final` to have a symbolic link on the Desktop named `2016-10 Fleet Week`.

I have tried many different varieties of the code I have posted down below, but the code I have included was the most concise code (although it didn't work).

Code description:

1. cd to Desktop so that symlinks are created there
2. use for loop to loop through folders
3. create symlink - here is the problem: I need to include the folder name in the file path somehow, but also add `\` before the spaces so that the command doesn't fail. HOWEVER, I have been getting error messages saying that there is no place called `RAID/Photos` which makes me think the script is stumbling on the first space, even with the backslash.
4. Change name of `Final` symlink to the folder name. (I assumed I didn't need full directories here because I'm already in Desktop

   ```
   cd Desktop
   for f in /Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos;
   do ln -s /Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos/"$f"/Final
   mv Final $f
   done
   ```

**QUESTION: Can someone please help me flush out this script? (I am mainly concerned with part three, but I wouldn't say no to help with the rest of it, either).**

Comment: Put double quotes around the `$f` in the mv command. Even if it is properly escaped when put into the variable, it will expand into multiple words when you use it without quoting.

Comment: @user3439894 good point! Question edited to reflect intent (only symlinks for final folders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running into troubles with shell quoting, it always help to add `echo` statements in suitable places in your script to see what's going on.

Let's look at this line by line:

```
for f in /Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos;
```

This only runs once, and sets `f` to `Volumes/Server RAID/Photos`, which probably isn't what you want.

```
do ln -s /Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos/"$f"/Final
```

`f` is set to the full path (see above), so this expands to

```
ln -s /Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos//Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos/Final
```

which (again) is not what you want to see here.

```
mv Final $f
```

See above :-)

There are various ways to tackle this, but in your case I would to something like the following (to get around the challenge of having to extract the directory name from the source path)

```
cd /Volumes/Server\ RAID/Photos/
for f in *; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then 
        if [ -d "$f"/Final ]; then
            ln -s "/Volumes/Server RAID/Photos/$f/Final" ~/Desktop/"$f"
        fi
    fi
done
```

The two `if`s cover the cases where there are files in the source directory or the `Final` directory is missing.